# Limpando borda de div com jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Como eu faço pra limpar a borda de uma DIV em Loop com jQuery?

Por exemplo,  eu estou com uma modal, fazendo loop de dados do banco de dados com Json, eu tenho um botao de selecionar cada item retornado dessa lista-(loop),
dai eu fiz o seguinte, criei um nome de classe: borda_310 <- borda_id_do_produto,
dai quando eu dou um selecionar eu consigo criar uma borda nesse item do loop, porém se eu selecionar os outros itens tambem seleciona, ou seja fica tudo seleciona os que eu cliquei, eu quero que clique em um e selecione, quando clicar em outro seleciona o outro e remove a borda do anterior.

Meu código HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3 li">
        <div class="product borda_' + data.dados[a].post_id + '">
            <ul class="product-labels"> 
                <li>' + data.dados[a].aluguei + '</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="product-img-wrap">
                <img class="product-img-primary" style="height:150px;" src="<?= BASE; ?>/uploads/' + data.dados[a].post_cover + '" alt="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" title="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" />
                <img class="product-img-alt" style="height:150px;" src="<?= BASE; ?>/uploads/' + data.dados[a].post_cover + '" alt="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" title="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" />
            </div>
            <div class="product-caption">
                <h5 class="product-caption-title">' + data.dados[a].post_title + '</h5>
                <div class="product-caption-price">
                    <span class="product-caption-price-new">
                        <a data-id_select="' + data.dados[a].post_id + '" class="btn btn-primary selecionar_jogo disabled_'+ data.dados[a].post_id +'" href="#">Selecionar</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Meu código jquery:

```
$(".lista_jogos").on("click", "a.selecionar_jogo", function (e) {
        var id_relacionamento = $(this).attr('id-jogo');
        var id_jogo = $(this).attr('data-id_select');
        $('.borda_' + id_jogo).attr('style', 'border:2px solid red');
        //alert(id_relacionamento+' - '+id_jogo);
    });
```

Aguardo alguém para resolver comigo o problema.

Comment: Acho que está fazendo errado, usando ids desnecessários que só vai dificultar seu código. Mostre o HTML para ver como está a estrutura dos elementos.

Comment: Coloquei aí o HTML

Comment: Outra coisa: desnecessário usar classes distintas apenas para saber que número ela tem para poder selecionar: `$('.borda_' + id_jogo)`... elementos com os mesmos estilos ou com a mesma finalidade devem ter a mesma classe. Identificação distinta deve ser usada apenas com ids, e algumas vezes nem precisa.

Comment: Na verdade criei essa classe aí apenas para diferenciar na hora do clique, mais como não sou expert em jQuery, fico aguardando a ajuda de você e de outros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere a classe da `div` para, deixando apenas `borda`:

```
<div class="product borda">
```

E o jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.selecionar_jogo", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".product.borda")
   .css("border", "none");

   $(this)
   .closest('.product.borda')
   .css('border', '2px solid red');
});
```

Aí você pode remover esse `data-id_select` se não servir pra nada.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).on("click", "a.selecionar_jogo", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".product.borda")
   .css("border", "none");
   
   $(this)
   .closest('.product.borda')
   .css('border', '2px solid red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 li">
     <div class="product borda">
         <ul class="product-labels"> 
             <li>' + data.dados[a].aluguei + '</li>
         </ul>
         <div class="product-img-wrap">
             <img class="product-img-primary" style="height:150px;" src="<?= BASE; ?>/uploads/' + data.dados[a].post_cover + '" alt="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" title="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" />
             <img class="product-img-alt" style="height:150px;" src="<?= BASE; ?>/uploads/' + data.dados[a].post_cover + '" alt="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" title="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" />
         </div>
         <div class="product-caption">
             <h5 class="product-caption-title">' + data.dados[a].post_title + '</h5>
             <div class="product-caption-price">
                 <span class="product-caption-price-new">
                     <a data-id_select="' + data.dados[a].post_id + '" class="btn btn-primary selecionar_jogo disabled_'+ data.dados[a].post_id +'" href="#">Selecionar</a>
                 </span>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="product borda">
         <ul class="product-labels"> 
             <li>' + data.dados[a].aluguei + '</li>
         </ul>
         <div class="product-img-wrap">
             <img class="product-img-primary" style="height:150px;" src="<?= BASE; ?>/uploads/' + data.dados[a].post_cover + '" alt="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" title="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" />
             <img class="product-img-alt" style="height:150px;" src="<?= BASE; ?>/uploads/' + data.dados[a].post_cover + '" alt="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" title="' + data.dados[a].post_title + '" />
         </div>
         <div class="product-caption">
             <h5 class="product-caption-title">' + data.dados[a].post_title + '</h5>
             <div class="product-caption-price">
                 <span class="product-caption-price-new">
                     <a data-id_select="' + data.dados[a].post_id + '" class="btn btn-primary selecionar_jogo disabled_'+ data.dados[a].post_id +'" href="#">Selecionar</a>
                 </span>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Deu certo mano, porém não posso remover os atributos, pq eu vou enviar via post para tratar no PHP, ficou perfeito, muito obrigado! Como faço pra obter seus serviços?